# PHP disable the automatic sending of a header

Tags: php, header, stdout, proc-open

I am trying to call an external CGI script from PHP and return the output from that script. In essence my PHP website will do authorisation and setup some environment parameters and then call the CGI script using a proc_open(). I want to return the stdout stream from the script directly back to the browser as it already contains a suitable HTTP header.

However with everything I try, php adds its own header before the contents of the CGI programs output. Is there anyway of completely turning off the php automatic header generation ?

```
// Rough code to pass HTTP request through an external CGI script and return response
function processRepo1(){
    $env = $_SERVER;
    $env["GIT_PROJECT_ROOT"] = "/data/git";
    $env["GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL"] = "YES";
    //$env["REQUEST_METHOD"] = "GET";
    $env["PATH_INFO"] = "/DuneNvme.git/info/refs";
    $env["QUERY_STRING"] = "service=git-upload-pack";

    if(1){
        $descriptorspec = array(
            0 => array("pipe", "r"),
            1 => array("pipe", "w"),
            2 => array("pipe", "w")
        );
    }
    else {
        $descriptorspec = array(
            0 => array("pipe", "r"),
            1 => fopen("php://stdout","w"),
            2 => fopen("php://stdout","w")
        );
    }

    $process = proc_open("/usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend", $descriptorspec, $pipes, Null, $env);
    if(is_resource($process)){
        // Disable php headers somehow ...

        fwrite($pipes[0], file_get_contents("php://input"));
        fclose($pipes[0]);

        echo stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
        fclose($pipes[2]);

        echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        $return_value = proc_close($process);
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        return "Process execution error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can replace the headers with the needed header, please provide an example for your code or the 'unneeded headers'

Comment: I don't want to replace the PHP produced header (like with header()) I simply want to send the raw stream from the CGI programs stdout back to the client browser. ie stop PHP producing any headers at all.

Comment: I guess you can't `escape` the headers, but you can `replace` them. that's what I can help!

Comment: Rough example code would be like:

Comment: What are these headers you want to remove?  PHP doesn't just add arbitrary headers...

Comment: Well something is adding the standard header packet including "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", "Date: Wed, 28 Oct 2020 06:57:06 GMT" etc. This is a Linux/apache/php-fpm/php7.3 system. I assumed the headers are being added to the return stream by php using some info supplied from apache. I will probably end up having to process the output of the CGI command and remove/merge its headers with the standard php returned ones but I was trying to do this efficiently/simply removing php processing.